# Orientation of photos in CSS form

Tags: php, css, forms, orientation, photo

I am makin form which taking photos from my database "ready to print" on A4 paper.
Some photos are orientated on height eg: 800x600 & some are eg 600x800. I need some php script which automaticly rotate horizontal photo to vertical & vertaly photos keep in their orientation.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657023/how-to-detect-shot-angle-of-photo-and-auto-rotate-for-website-display-like-desk

Answer (score 0):

you can use imagerotate with php..
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
$filename="image.jpg";


// get the width and height from the image
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);

//if image width is bigger then the height it will execute the following script
if ($width > height){

 // Load the image
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

//and save it on your server...
file_put_contents("myNEWimage.jpg",$rotate);

}
```

You might do some adjustments and testing. are busy at work atm so dont have time to test it.

Greetings

Comment: I receied this: Notice: Undefined variable: degrees in /home/doprava/www/dano/foto.php on line 70

Warning: file_put_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /new/index.php on line 73

Comment: hmm make a far $degrees = 90; what does it output then?